# Why do my objects still look blocky even after adding a subdiv modifier?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I added a subdiv modifier, but some parts of my mesh still look bad; in the preview, however, it looks a lot better. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: What does it look liked when actually rendered? I find the viewport to sometimes show things inaccurately.

Comment: This is caused by what's known as the "terminator problem". The only real solution is to add more geometry (i.e. another level of subsurf).

Comment: In my experience Blender does not like more than 6 or 7 levels of subdiv in the modifier. You may have to subdivide your mesh once or twice first, and then reduce the subdiv modifier.

Comment: The actual render is on the right, and yes, the shadows of the object are the ones giving me troubles.

Comment: [Definitely a Terminator issue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VQUi8.jpg)... : ) Bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T37814

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh I've never seen *blender* have any troubles with such levels of subsurf, only my poor processor :P Though even then only when subdividing a not-very-lowpoly base mesh. Judging by the OPs screenshot I'd say you could handle one, *maybe* two more levels without much trouble. Though I'd only increase it for the render, no need to subdivide that much in the viewport unless you are actively working the shaders for that object or something.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, I meant in viewport mode, and it does depend on your machine specs, but in general I think it applies.

Comment: Yes. I just want to be clear that it's the *number of faces*, not the number of subdivisions, which counts towards poor performance.

Comment: Yes, of course, which the subdivision levels are a multiplier of.